# Cookies and Random Numbers in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, random

It's a quick question:

How can I generate cookies with a random identifier ?

I mean I'm trying to set a cookie whose name comes from a rand number and then I try to read the cookie but I get errors.

```
$random = rand(1,1000);
setCookie($random,'value',time()+3600,"/");
echo $_COOKIE[$random]; //and I get a Undefined offset
```

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Comment: Undefine Offset: (here goes the generated random number for the name of the cookie)

Comment: You cannot read a cookie from `$_COOKIE` that you have just set using `setcookie`! The page needs to reload first. Try `var_dump($_COOKIE)` for illustration.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php You are using an integer to set the name

Comment: Var dump shows me a null in the cookie.

trone, I'm converting the rand value into String with strval();

and nothing, I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: If you're using a random name for the cookie, then you'll have to manually foreach over $_COOKIE (on the next page request, when the cookie actually gets transmitted) to find it again. -- Maybe take a step back, and tell what you actually wanted to do.

Comment: It's done, it's a problem of organization, all cookies were created the problem was that when I reload the page to verify the cookie the page generates a new cookie with a random value and the verification of the new one is ignored.

So I decided to isolate in one page the creation of the cookie and in other page the verification of the cookie.

Other question because I'm new with cookies:

PHP Cookies are stored in the cliend or in the server?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your cookie is NULL of the following (pay attention to the bolded text):

> Once the cookies have been set, **they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE** or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals
>   such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also
>   exist in $_REQUEST.

Your code sets the cookie with a name of the current generated number.  You can't actually access the cookie until you reload the page/navigate to a new page.

If you are refreshing this page you are first generating a new random number and setting it to $random.  Then setting a new cookie (which again can only be accessed after a page load) with the current $random, then trying to retrieve a cookie using that same $random variable which has already been updated with a new number and set on a new cookie that isn't available until a new page load =)

Does that make sense?

---

**EDIT**

I just saw you came to that conclusion on your own.  To answer your question asking if cookies are saved client side or server side: client side in the browser.

If you are going to be working with cookies a lot I recommend a great Google Chrome plugin called EditThisCookie that will help see which cookies are being set and important information about each of them:

[EditThisCookie Plugin](http://www.editthiscookie.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
The valid command is setcookie NOT setCookie
 Solutions:
 <?php
$random = md5(rand(1,1000)); //encoded with md5, avoid bad string output.
/* Random Value */
setcookie("TestCookie", $random, time()+3600); 
$_COOKIE['TestCookie'] = $random;
/* Random Cookiename */
$randomcookie = $random;
setcookie($random, "value", time()+3600);
$_COOKIE[$randomcookie] = "TestCookie";
$_SESSION['randomcookie'] = $_COOKIE[$randomcookie]; //put into session for saved on cache localhost
/* Output */
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"]; //output your random cookievalue
echo $_SESSION["randomcookie"]; //output your random cookiename
  ?>
```